# Event for Android Pay purchase?

Tags: java, android, events, android-pay

I'd like to know if there is any way for an app to listen for Android Pay purchase events (even purchases made through a different app), and get information such as amount of purchase and name of merchant? I scoured through the API but am not finding anything.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @Dec no, not yet. I gave up on it a little.